# SharePoint knowledge

Tags: administration, tools

I need to be a SharePoint site admin, the truth is I´ve never used sharepoint before and I don´t know what is needed to become an expert, could you tell me the tools I need to have and the knowledge needed to become a good sharepoint admin?
Thanks and regards

Answer (score 1):

As far as knowledge, you just need to spend time working in the environment.  You can look through many different resources and get good ideas of what to do, but until you sit down and do it yourself it's not the same.  You won't become an 'expert' in any short time, but you can learn the basics fairly quick and take it one step at a time after that.  I spend plenty of time reading through this site and others to learn many different things.

There are many different resources both online and at your local bookstore that can give you plenty of information. There are a lot of books that go through varying stages of knowledge within SP as well.  For a complete beginner like yourself, a book like [Microsoft SharePoint 2013 Plain & Simple](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0735667004) would be good.  It puts the basics out there in a quite visual manner.

Source: Recent college grad that had never used SharePoint before I started my job ~3 months ago.  Now feel quite comfortable with most things, but still learning everyday.

Answer (score 0):

A Learning Roadmap provides a methodical approach to help you build expertise as you achieve a series of learning goals. You start with prerequisites and then build on your knowledge and experience in levels:

- Introductory (level 100)
- Intermediate (level 200)
- Advanced (level 300)
- Expert (level 400)
  Watch the video for this link to understand more about the road map and resources.
  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj937861(v=office.15).aspx

Check this Technet for SharePoint Training videos;

[SharePoint 2013 training for IT pros](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dn756397.aspx)

You can also check the paid training video training.

[SharePoint 2013 Training Courses](http://sharepoint-videos.com/video-categories/sharepoint-2013-training-courses/)
[SharePoint 2013 Admin Videos](http://www.infiniteskills.com/training/learning-to-administer-sharepoint-server-2013.html)
http://www.lynda.com/
http://www.pluralsight.com/training/Courses#sharepoint

Some of above sites having free trial, you can check that as well.